# Android Button is greyed out after enabling it

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have a button that is disabled by default (in the XML, the `enabled` attribute is set to `false`).

When I want to enable the button from within the code (by using `setEnabled(true)`), it stays greyed out but becomes clickable. Also, as soon as I click it, it changes it apperance to the regular, enabled one.

I have already tried calling `refreashDrawableState()` after enabling the button, but I had no success with that.

This is the code that I currently use to enabled the button (`getWriteRXBtn()` returns the button instance).

```
getWriteRXBtn().setEnabled(true);
getWriteRXBtn().refreshDrawableState();
```

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Are you running this code on the UI thread? If not, can you try using `runOnUIThread()`?

Comment: Share your code.. without it nobody can actually help you..

Comment: @JensV if it was not run from UI thread it would throw an exception

Comment: Have you tried to set `enabled` to `true` in XML and then set it to `false` in code?

Comment: @JensV Your solution was correct, it works now. Thank you.